# What does it mean "the vector be symmetrically disposed about their common origin"

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand the math behind the following paper (links provided below) with the comment **"...the vector be symmetrically disposed about their common origin"**.

Does it mean that all the vector is starting from the origin?

Charles L. Fortescue, "Method of Symmetrical Co-Ordinates Applied to the Solution of Polyphase Networks". Presented at the 34th annual convention of the AIEE (American Institute of Electrical Engineers) in Atlantic City, N.J. on 28 June 1918. Published in: AIEE Transactions, vol. 37, part II, pages 1027–1140 (1918). For a brief history of the early years of symmetrical component theory, see: J. Lewis Blackburn, Symmetrical Components for Power Engineering (Boca Raton, Florida: CRC Press, 1993), pages 3–4.

http://www.energyscienceforum.com/files/fortescue/methodofsymmetrical.pdf

Comment: Vectors don’t have common origins because vectors are not arrows. It seems they consider the situation that the three vectors are of equal length and sum to zero. Geometrically they then form an equilateral triangle with the origin as centre

Comment: The book is using the language of its time, so these are localised vectors, so the common origin is not a problem. I think that if distinct $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n$ have common origin $O$ then we say they are symmetrically disposed if the set is invariant under a rotation of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$.